# How to mock the Expect::expect() function in perl

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking, expect

I am stuck while mocking a piece of code that involves the Expect::expect function in perl

It goes like this:

```
my $result = 0;
my $exp = new Expect;
$exp->raw_pty(1);
$exp->log_stdout(0);
$exp->spawn("$some_command");

$exp->expect(undef,
    [ qr/some text/i,
        sub { my $self = shift;
            $self->send("$a_param\n");
            exp_continue;
        } ],
    [ qr/more text/,
        sub { my $self = shift;
            $self->send("$another_param");
            sleep 5;
            exp_continue;
        } ],
    [ qr/some more text/ ,
        sub { my $self = shift;
            $ld_info = "$something";
            $self->clear_accum();
            $self->send($ld_info);
            sleep 5;
            exp_continue;
        } ],

    [ qr/further more text/,
        sub { my $self = shift;
            $result = 1;
        } ],
);
return $result;}
```

The value of $result is the final return value. While mocking I intend to set the value of result to 1 without actually running a command and then trying to match patterns. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it by using a

```
local *
```

implementation to replace code with your own code.
It actually depends on how the function is called, but I think you can go with something like:

```
local *Expect::expect = sub
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi ChatterOne, Thanks a lot for your reply, that actually helps.
What I am trying to do here is to set the $result variable which happens when the last condition becomes true. Is there a way I can mock this scenario? Just returning 1 won't solve my purpose I guess.I would still give a try to what you suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correctly, but by the code you posted (which because of that last curly brace I assume is incomplete), it looks like $result is set only after Expect::expect has run. If you want you can mock your own entire function, or the whole class Expect, using the same technique.